# Cordova Build Android Errors

Tags: java, android, html, ios, cordova

Please help, I have a problem when making an android application with Cordova, already at this step and experiencing obstacles like in the picture ..

Thankyou for the response

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Download JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) and remove all other versions